# PIR sensor using 3.3v?

Tags: gpio

I have 2 PIR sensors that i want to use on my Raspberry Pi however both 5v's are being used and I'm left with the 3.3vs and am unsure if i am able to use it as it may damage the board? Here is a link to the sensor i am using.

https://thepihut.com/products/pir-motion-sensor-module?_pos=2&_sid=82d3c4c4c&_ss=r

Comment: You can power multiple devices from one power pin.

Comment: How would i do that? @joan

Comment: Join two wires together.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 5V rail using a breadboard. If not that, then you can use a 9V battery and pass it through a voltage regulator like lm7805 to get the desired voltage. To create a rail, connect 5V to one of last two horizontal rows of your breadboard

Comment: (+1) however that's not necessary. As @joan stated simply connect it to the same pin